# Datagridview virtual model combobox

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

how can you dynamically add items to a combobox using the datagridview virtual mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I assume you are working with a very large set of data, and thus are using virtual mode to implement your own data binding.

If that is the case here is a link that demonstrates the process:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b177d6d.aspx

It primarily involves implementing an event handler for the CellValueNeeded event.